# IBMDB2 simple query error 901 - system error

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I'm working on a IBM iseries v6r1m0 system.

I'm trying to execute a very simple query :

```
select * from XG.ART where DOS = 998 and (DES like 'ALB%' or DESABR like 'ALB%')
```

The columns are:

```
DOS -> numeric (3,0)
DES -> Graphic(80) CCSID 1200
DESABR -> Garphic(25) CCSID 1200
```

I get :

```
SQL State : 58004
SQL Code : -901
Message : [SQL0901] SQL System error. 
Cause . . . . . :  An SQL system error has occurred. The current SQL statement cannot be completed successfully. The error will not prevent other SQL statements from being processed. Previous messages may indicate that there is a problem with the SQL statement and SQL did not correctly diagnose the error. The previous message identifier was CPF4204. Internal error type 3107 has occurred. If precompiling, processing will not continue beyond this statement.
Recovery . . . : See the previous messages to determine if there is a problem with the SQL statement. To view the messages, use the DSPJOBLOG command if running interactively, or the WRKJOB command to view the output of a precompile. An application program receiving this return code may attempt further SQL statements. Correct any errors and try the request again.
```

If I change DES into REF (graphic(25)), it works...

EDIT :

I run some tests this afternoon, and it is very strange :

Just after the creation of the table/indexes, I have no errors.

- If I insert some datas : error
- If I clear the table : error
- If I remove an index (see below) : it works (with or without datas)
  !!

The index is :

```
create index XG.GTFAT_ART_B on XG.ART(
DOS,
DESABR,
ART_ID
)
```

Edit 2 :

Here is the job log (sorry, it is in French...)
[image: joblog]

It sais :

```
Function error X'1720' in machine instruction. Internal snapshot ID 01010054
Foo file created in library QTEMP.
*** stuff with the printer
DBOP *** FAILED open. Exception from call to SLIC$
Internal error in the query processor file
Sql system error
```

Comment: You don't have to wrap `DESABR`?  Confirmation would be nice, but I'm assuming you're changing the dds file.  It sounds like there may be some sort of invalid/strange data in `DES`.

Comment: @X-Zero : What do you meant by wrap DESABR ? I've added some infos...

Comment: What is the creation script for the table?  What I'm getting at is, did you have to change the definition of `DESABR` to make things work, or only `DOS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally contacted IBM.

It was an old bug from v5.

I have installed the latest PTF, and now, it works.

Comment: What PTF do you need to install?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [GRAPHIC](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzscagraphic.htm) scalar function to convert your character literals on the [LIKE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzch2like.htm) predicate.

```
CREATE TABLE QTEMP/TEST (F1 GRAPHIC(80))
INSERT INTO QTEMP/TEST (F1) VALUES (GRAPHIC('TEST'))
SELECT * FROM QTEMP/TEST WHERE F1 LIKE GRAPHIC('TE%')
```

Comment: With your example, I get on the insert statement : SQL State : 57017
SQL Code : -332
Message : [SQL0332] Character conversion between CCSID 1147 and CCSID 1147 incorrect

Comment: @Xavinou I didn't realize your job was already in DBCS.  Can you include the joblog prior to the SQL0901 error?  The diagnostic messages should provide a clue as to what the problem is.

Comment: @Xavinou That is a failure in the system licensed internal code.  I would suggest making sure you are current on your CUME and group PTF's and if the problem still exists contact IBM support.

Answer (score 0):

I know this guy got his problem fixed with an update.  But here is something that worked for me that might work for the next guy here who has the problem.

My problem query had a lot of common table expressions.  Most of them did not create tables with a whole lot of records.  So if I figured that the maximum number of records a CTE would make was 1000, I added a "Fetch first 9999 rows only" to it.  I knew that the CTE couldn't possibly have more rows than that. I guess the query optimizer had less to think about with that added.

If you have that problem and you don't have the option to upgrade or talk to IBM, I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

For other people getting this errore, I encountered it on an IBM i Series v7r3, when tried an `UPDATE`, retrieving the value to be set on a field using a inner `SELECT` where multiple results where reduced to 1, using `DISTINCT`. I solved the problem removing `DISTINCT` and adding `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` at the end of the inner SELECT.

E.g.: changed from

```
UPDATE MYTABLE AS T1  
SET T1.FIELD1 = (
    SELECT DISTINCT T2.FIELD5
    FROM MYTABLE AS T2       
    WHERE T1.FIELD2 = T2.FIELD2
      AND T1.FIELD3 = T2.FIELD3
    )
WHERE T1.FIELD4 = 'XYZ'
```

to

```
UPDATE MYTABLE AS T1  
SET T1.FIELD1 = (
    SELECT T2.FIELD5
    FROM MYTABLE AS T2       
    WHERE T1.FIELD2 = T2.FIELD2
      AND T1.FIELD3 = T2.FIELD3
    FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
    )
WHERE T1.FIELD4 = 'XYZ'
```